# Space between Page title and first Page item/region

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm working with APEX oracle 23.1
I created a modal page containing one report (or can be one item of text field). However, I observed that there's a gap between page title and the report (or item) as the following image. May I ask if it is possible to remove that gap?

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: I've just tested it on 23.2 - no such gap. Is there, by any chance, an **item** that isn't displayed, but "reserves" some space? It would be great if you could create sample application on apex.oracle.com, share developer's credentials so that we could have a look.

Comment: You can also use the "inspect element" browser tool to help give a hint as the type of content that is hidden here. It may even be a breadcrumb on your global page that has no entry for the modal.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's the dialog header from a breadcumb. I manage to hide it using CSS.

Comment: Why would you hide it using css ? Just remove the breadcrumb component from the page in the builder. This probably happened because you created a normal page (which includes a breadcrumb component) and then changed it to modal.

Answer (score 0):

Check your report's Appearance > Template Options > Top Margin

You may try to set to `none` and see any changes or not.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I did try it but no luck.